# How to change the TeXForm output while exporting an array to LaTeX format?

Tags: export, latex, output-formatting

I have an array in Mathematica, which I would like to export to a file in TeX format.

```
data={{1.2, 1.0429, "0.440773(65)", 1.665 \[PlusMinus] 1.85*10^-2}, 
{1.3, 2.9496, "0.859618(21)", 0.911 \[PlusMinus] 3.02*10^-2},
{1.4, 0.9916, "0.191505(74)", 4.755 \[PlusMinus] 4.64*10^-2}, 
{1.5, 1.6394, "0.811863(52)", 1.507 \[PlusMinus] 8.05*10^-2}};
```

Due to the options that I'm using to generate my document with LaTeX, the entries in the last column must be enclosed in `{$ xxx $}`, so the output must look like this:

```
  1.2 & 1.0429 & \text{0.440773(65)} & {$ 1.665\pm 0.0185 $} \\
  1.3 & 2.9496 & \text{0.859618(21)} & {$ 0.911\pm 0.0302 $} \\
  1.4 & 0.9916 & \text{0.191505(74)} & {$ 4.755\pm 0.0464 $} \\
  1.5 & 1.6394 & \text{0.811863(52)} & {$ 1.507\pm 0.0805 $} \\
```

`Grid[data]//TeXForm` almost yields the correct result but it doesn't enclose the entries of column four in `{$ xxx $}`. Is there a way to specify the format of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> four in {$ xxx $}. Is there a way to specify the format of the
> columns?

I am a little confused. Why do you need to do this? In your Latex, just enclose the whole output in an equation so the whole thing becomes in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1.2 & 1.0429 & \text{0.440773(65)} & 1.665\pm 0.0185 \\
 1.3 & 2.9496 & \text{0.859618(21)} & 0.911\pm 0.0302 \\
 1.4 & 0.9916 & \text{0.191505(74)} & 4.755\pm 0.0464 \\
 1.5 & 1.6394 & \text{0.811863(52)} & 1.507\pm 0.0805 \\
\end{array}
\]                            
\end{document}
```

You can add the `\[...\]` inside your latex document, or add it inside Mathematica, depending on how you are doing things.  When you compile the above in Latex, here is the output

[image]

> I'm using tabular

Well, you could always convert it by "hand" as this is easy enough. (this is how I actually generate all my Latex documents from Mathematica)

```
data = {{1.2, 1.0429, "0.440773(65)", 
    1.665 \[PlusMinus] 1.85*10^-2}, {1.3, 2.9496, "0.859618(21)", 
    0.911 \[PlusMinus] 3.02*10^-2}, {1.4, 0.9916, "0.191505(74)", 
    4.755 \[PlusMinus] 4.64*10^-2}, {1.5, 1.6394, "0.811863(52)", 
    1.507 \[PlusMinus] 8.05*10^-2}};
toX[s_] := ToString@TeXForm[s];
{nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[data];
s = "\\begin{tabular}" <> Table["c", {nCol}] <> "}
   ";
Do[
  Do[
   If[m == 1, s = s <> toX@data[[n, m]],
    If[m == nCol, s = s <> "&{$" <> toX@data[[n, m]] <> "$}\\\\
       ", s = s = s <> "&" <> toX@data[[n, m]]]]
   , {m, 1, nCol}
   ]
  , {n, 1, nRow}
  ];
s = s <> "\\end{tabular}
   ";

s
```

Gives

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
1.2&1.0429&\text{0.440773(65)}&{$1.665\pm 0.0185$}\\
1.3&2.9496&\text{0.859618(21)}&{$0.911\pm 0.0302$}\\
1.4&0.9916&\text{0.191505(74)}&{$4.755\pm 0.0464$}\\
1.5&1.6394&\text{0.811863(52)}&{$1.507\pm 0.0805$}\\
\end{tabular}
```

Compiles as

[image]

Do you want frame? Then do

```
data = {{1.2, 1.0429, "0.440773(65)", 
    1.665 \[PlusMinus] 1.85*10^-2}, {1.3, 2.9496, "0.859618(21)", 
    0.911 \[PlusMinus] 3.02*10^-2}, {1.4, 0.9916, "0.191505(74)", 
    4.755 \[PlusMinus] 4.64*10^-2}, {1.5, 1.6394, "0.811863(52)", 
    1.507 \[PlusMinus] 8.05*10^-2}};
toX[s_] := ToString@TeXForm[s];
{nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[data];
s = "\\begin{tabular}{" <> Table["|c", {nCol}] <> "|}\\hline
   ";
Do[
  Do[
   If[m == 1, s = s <> toX@data[[n, m]],
    If[m == nCol, s = s <> "&{$" <> toX@data[[n, m]] <> "$}\\\\\\hline
       ", s = s = s <> "&" <> toX@data[[n, m]]]]
   , {m, 1, nCol}
   ]
  , {n, 1, nRow}
  ];
s = s <> "\\end{tabular}
   ";

s
```

gives

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
1.2&1.0429&\text{0.440773(65)}&{$1.665\pm 0.0185$}\\\hline
1.3&2.9496&\text{0.859618(21)}&{$0.911\pm 0.0302$}\\\hline
1.4&0.9916&\text{0.191505(74)}&{$4.755\pm 0.0464$}\\\hline
1.5&1.6394&\text{0.811863(52)}&{$1.507\pm 0.0805$}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Which compiles as

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In LaTeX I'm using `tabular` along with `siunitx` in order to align the numbers by decimal points. If an entry has a symbol in math mode, it has to be wrapped in curly braces. Otherwise LaTeX won't [compile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-table-columns#comment157040_2746) :-(.